# Why is __eq__() allowed to return an arbitrary data type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been messing around trying to write a "robust" method of determining if arbitrary objects in a collection are equal and what I quickly discovered was that determining equality in python isn't exactly easy. I believe this is in part due to python allowing overrides of the `__eq__` operator to return a value of arbitrary type. This allows data structures like `ndarray`s, `dataframe`s, etc. to do element-wise comparisons when `__eq__` is called.

While that provides a lot of convenience for users who often need to do such comparisons, it makes the concept of equality extremely vague (as recognized by the exceptions that get raised when trying to do something like `if array1 == array2: do something`). In order to get what I want (which is a result that lets me know whether or not I can swap the objects in any context defined for the types being compared and get the same result) I then have to do `array.all()` or `dataframe.equals()` or something that I don't know ahead of time if I don't know the type of object I am working with.

My question is essentially this: **What issues are being avoided by python's decision to allow `__eq__` to return an arbitrary data type?**

Comment: Python letting you override `__eq__` has a rough parallel in pretty much every language I know of. It's either object identity or it's something arbitrary you invent that makes sense for your class. I'm not sure what you expect here.

Comment: @ggorlen The question is about the return value though.

Comment: So you think Python should run a check for type upon every call to `__eq__`? That isn't really in keeping with most duck typed languages -- it's just a value treated as a boolean by context. If Python's library functions type checked everything by hand, it'd defeat the purpose of duck typing.

Comment: @ggorlen Not really an answer, because Python does run a check for type upon every call to `__str__` (try overriding it returning an int value and see what happens).

Comment: Yes, it checks some things where it makes sense, but can you show a type checked boolean call? I'm not saying they don't exist, but they're definitely non-typical.

Comment: @ggorlen Most dunder methods perform a type check. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: Which raise if you don't return a boolean?

Comment: @ggorlen `__bool__`, for example.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, they will raise a `TypeError` (`__bool__`, `__hash__`, `__bytes__`, `__str__`, etc).

Comment: `if A(): pass` does give `TypeError`. Python will not type check if you use the dunder methods directly.

Comment: Directly calling the method is not the same thing as `bool(A())`. In your case you are using the dunder method as a regular method.

Comment: Ah, OK, I stand corrected. Are there any other examples besides this one? It makes sense that `__bool__` enforces it, but throughout the rest of the library it seems Python uses boolean context, so I'm not really convinced fully yet. I don't find `__eq__`'s behavior at all surprising or inconsistent with the language.

Comment: @ggorlen I listed a few others in my comment above.

Comment: Those aren't related to booleans through. The return values of these functions aren't evaluated in a boolean context, so they don't seem relevant to `__eq__`.

Comment: @ggorlen No, that was related to your initial comment: `If Python's library functions type checked everything by hand, it'd defeat the purpose of duck typing.` . `__eq__` is already an exception, that's why we have this question here.

Comment: Yes, emphasis on the word "everything". I realize plenty of stuff is checked by hand so you can come up with counterexamples, but just as much isn't, and that's the point. Booleans almost never are (okay, `__bool__` yes, but what else)? We're trying to figure out if `__eq__` is surprising or not by not type checking, and I don't see that it is because of a single base-case counterexample due to `__bool__`.

Comment: It looks like you already know about the motivating use cases - you mentioned NumPy arrays, which are the reason rich comparisons were added to the language.

Comment: @ggorlen The problem is that you can't answer "it would kill duck typing if there was a type check" to "why `__eq__` allows returning non-booleans" as you initially did because there indeed are some dunder methods where type checks occur.

Comment: Simply `array1 == array2` returning an array-like is already pretty convincing reason to me!

Comment: @enzo Maybe so, but I'm trying to understand OP's source of confusion/surprise here. I'm asking: if OP thinks it should type check everything, or even most things, well, that's clearly not a reasonable expectation, especially for booleans where I don't see any precedent besides `__bool__` for something actually being type checked in Python. Given that, the burden of proof should be: why _should_ Python type check something, not why shouldn't it. For `__bool__`, there's a good reason to type check, but for `__eq__` I don't see any reason to. The default mode is boolean context.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__):

> By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an if statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

So it is possible to override the `==` operator in a non-Boolean context, e.g.:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.x == other.x:
      return "equal"
    else:
      return "not equal"
```

then

```
print(MyClass(1) == MyClass(2))
```

will print

```
not equal
```

Obviously it is not very useful for the `==` operator, but might make sense for other rich comparison operators such as `>`.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I am not sure it answers what I am trying to ask. I know it is possible to override it to do/return whatever the creator of the class wants. My question is that given the difficulties it introduces when trying to compare objects of unknown type, what benefits does it offer or what pitfalls does it avoid?

Comment: That's basically what the documentation says (in reverse). When used in a Boolean context, Python will use the `bool()` built-in to convert it to a boolean. That is, you don't have to use it in a Boolean context. Say you have an array-like data structure. You can then override the `<` such that it returns a copy of the array, shifted to left by 1 element (yes, I know it's better to override `<<` in this case but still).

Comment: @jammertheprogrammer I just don't see this as a source of significant difficulties. I suspect that we would understand better if you elaborate on "In order to get what I want (which is a result that lets me know whether or not I can swap the objects in any context defined for the types being compared and get the same result)" What exactly do you mean? I can't think of any time I'd need something like that, but then, I'm not sure I understand